# Compare tables from different databases with the same data but different number of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

In Oracle SQL Developer, how do I compare three tables where A + B = C table? I have to validate if all the data of A and B is converted into C. Also table A is in a different database from B and C, which are in the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that the different databases have one column, an `id`.  You could use `full outer join` for this, assuming it is never `NULL`.  However, this is probably easier using `union all` and aggregation.

You can get a list of ids that differ using the following query:

```
select id, sum(inab) as inab, sum(inc) as inc
from ((select id, 1 as inab, 0 as inc
       from a
      ) union all
      (select id, 1 as inab, 0 as inc
       from b
      ) union all
      (select id, 0 as inab, 1 as inc
       from c
      ) 
     ) c
group by id
having sum(inab) <> 1 or sum(inc) <> 1;
```

In practice, you would probably have multiple columns.  Note:  if there are duplicates in A+B or C, this just guarantees that the duplicate appears in both (rather than in both with the same count).

Comment: what does inab mean? inc mean? and the number of columns in B and C are same but differ in A. so how does UNION ALL work here

Comment: Those are column aliases, an important part of the SQL language, as is `UNION ALL`.